# Decode In Denominator

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to do a decode on denominator however getting divisor equals 0 error ! How can I get pass this error ?

```
ROUND(
    SUM( DECODE(O.STUDENT_ID,450,0,T.STUDENT_AFFECTED) * T.EXAM_MINUTES)
    / 
    SUM(DECODE(O.STUDENT_ID,450,0,T.STUDENT_AFFECTED)),1) STUDENT_WO710,
```

Comment: You've written the decode to generate 0 when the ID is 450 - hence the error. What do you want to happen? It isn't clear what you are trying to calculate - maybe you wanted the denominator to be a count, not a sum? It would help if you edited the question to gives some sample data and the result you expect for it, and why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are grouping by `O.STUDENT_ID` then you could rewrite your statement so that the `DECODE` surrounds the aggregation rather than being inside of it:

```sql
SELECT O.STUDENT_ID,
       ROUND(
        DECODE(
          O.STUDENT_ID,
          450, 0,
          SUM(T.STUDENT_AFFECTED * T.EXAM_MINUTES) / SUM(T.STUDENT_AFFECTED)
        ),
        1
      ) AS STUDENT_WO710
FROM  table_name o
GROUP BY student_id;
```